# How to add a column rows interval in epplus?

Tags: c#, epplus

I'm trying to evaluate all the cell columns value from H to Y, I don't know the number of rows, I only know the number of cells. 
What I tried:

```
var address = new ExcelAddress("H:Y");
var condition = ws.ConditionalFormatting.AddExpression(address);
    condition.Style.Font.Color.Color = Color.Red;
    condition.Formula = "IF(H2 < 25, 1, 0)";
```

As you can see I set as address H to Y and this working well but, there is a problem. I've an header on the first row H1, and I don't need to evaluate it, so I need to start from the second row H2 until Y2, but if I change the interval as: `var address = new ExcelAddress("H2:Y2");` I get the color applied only on the second row and not for the other rows.

How can I manage this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your question well you can do the following:

First, know the rows count using:

```
int row = workSheet.Dimension.End.Row;
```

Then you can achieve what you want using the following address:

```
var address = new ExcelAddress($"H2:Y{rows}");
```

Comment: this seems to working, but why the last line isn't colored?

Comment: Maybe it is violating the condition, can you check that?